# What is GPU Boost in NVIDIA GPU

Tags: gpu

What exactly is [GPU Boost](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/gpu-boost/technology) and how it helps? What is the improvement in GPU Boost 2.0? I did not understand much reading from the link. Can somebody explain the main concept and details?

Answer (score 3):

If I read correctly, GPU Boost 2.0 ramps up the clock speed of the GPU cores until a target temperature is reached. It sounds like a closed-loop controller than runs the GPU as hot as possible but no hotter.